# Получить id элемента вызвавшего событие(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

**Форма:**

```
 <form method="DELETE" action="" id="deleteForm">
      <c:forEach var="flight" items="${flights}">
             <tr>
               <td>${flight.id}</td>
               <td>${flight.navigation}</td>
               <td>${flight.team.id}</td>
               <td><input type="submit" value="Delete flight" id="${flight.id}" onclick="deleteButtonClickHandler(event)"></td>
               </tr>
      </c:forEach>
 </form>
```

**Обработчик:**

```
(function () {
    var idFlight = 0;
    function deleteButtonClickHandler(event) {
      idFlight = //id кнопки
    }   
})();
```

**Вопрос:**
Как получить id кнопки вызвавшей функцию обработки?

Comment: @Igor <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" onLoad="load()">

Comment: зачем ты отредактировал вопрос, полностью изменив исходный код?

Comment: @Grundy, ты? сейчас верну

Comment: @bsuart - плохо. Функция `deleteButtonClickHandler` - локальная внутри автовызываемой и в глобальной области видимости `onclick="deleteButtonClickHandler(event)"` - отсутствует.

Comment: @Igor, спасибо, понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вытянуть инфу по `event.target.id`:

```js
function deleteButtonClickHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  idFlight = event.target.id;
  console.log(idFlight);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="id 22" id="22" onclick="deleteButtonClickHandler(event)">
<input type="submit" value="id 23" id="23" onclick="deleteButtonClickHandler(event)">
<input type="submit" value="id 24" id="24" onclick="deleteButtonClickHandler(event)">
```

К слову, вы всегда можете поставить `debugger` и просмотреть текущие значения (просто наведите мышью на `event`).

Comment: @bsuart добавьте структуру проекта ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/666430/edit))